# Focus gain and lose by clicking on EditText in android

Tags: android

I have two edittext editextone and edittexttwo. Bydefault the edttextone should be focused then after when user click on edttexttwo then edttexttwo should get focus and edttextone will lose focus. now if user click on edttextone then edttextone should get focus and edttexttwo lose focus. please help me how can i achieve this.

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior?

Comment: As Pankaj Kumar said . its default behaviour//

Comment: i have managed to get default focus on edttextone but after clicking on edttexttwo focus should be on edttexttwo and edttextone should lose focus